# CommCare Supply: How do I figure out what a Program's ID is?

Tags: commcare

I want to limit the Products displayed in one form of my app to only those from  one Program. Where and how can I see what a Program's ID is to that I can use it in the display logic? All HQ shows me is a Program's name, not ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to determine the program ID is open the program edit page on CommCare HQ and pull the ID from the URL (it is the long set of characters at the end of the url not including the slash).

A more general answer whenever you need to inspect or reference CommCare data being sent to a device is to [view the user restore sent to the device](https://confluence.dimagi.com/display/commcarepublic/OTA+Restore+API). This would show you the XML-formatted list of `program` data (which is represented as a CommCare fixture) and show you the IDs you need associated with each program.

[image]